# FileSystemWatcher - Changed Event for ReadOnly Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher, readonly-attribute

It looks like the FileSystemMonitor is not firing a 'Changed' event (and no other events) when the ReadOnly attribute of a file in the monitored directory is changed.

This is my test code:

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;

    namespace FSM
    {
        class Program
        {
            static FileSystemWatcher FolderMonitor;


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            FolderMonitor = new FileSystemWatcher("C:\\MyImages");
            FolderMonitor.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            FolderMonitor.Changed += FolderMonitor_Changed; ;
            FolderMonitor.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to terminate .....");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }


        private static void FolderMonitor_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("****  \"" + e.Name + "\" changed.");
        }
    }
```

With that code, I am receiving a lot of 'Changed' events, e.g. if the modification timestamp has changed, but not if I am changing any standard attributes like ReadOnly or Hidden.

Am I missing something, or have I hit a "feature"?

Comment: Seems odd. The docs say _"The Changed event is raised when changes are made to the size, **system attributes**, last write time, last access time, or security permissions of a file or directory in the directory being monitored."_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `NotifyFilter` property as this determines the type of changes that are watched for. See [FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter(v=vs.110).aspx)

e.g.

```
FolderMonitor.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes;
```

Comment: Yes, indeed, I had missed setting the NotifyFilter property. I have added the following line to my code:
          FolderMonitor.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
    | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName
    | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Security;
It works now perfect!
My problem had been that the Changed event seemed to be working for me - but only because of a default setting of the NotifyFilter which was not sufficient for my task.
Thank you!